# x2go Client leads to a frozen scrren with the following pop-up message

Tags: 20.04

[image]

Image description: Problem in wrapper-2.0
" Sorry, the program "wrapper-2.0" closed unexpectedly

I cannot navigate into the desktop at all due to the screen being completely frozen. I also do not have access to the actual Ubuntu server to go and make any updates to it. Please suggest what I can do from my end.